# I'm completely blanking on a simple exponent problem

Tags: self-learning

Solve for $x$:

$5x^{0.7}$ $=$ $y$

Comment: Take logarithm on both sides, and then isolate the $x$ on one side, before exponentiating both sides.

Comment: $x^{0.7}=\frac y 5\implies x=(0.2y )^{10/7}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5x^{0.7}=y$$

$$x^{0.7}=\frac{y}{5}$$

$$0.7\ln x=\ln\frac{y}{5}$$

$$\ln x=\frac{\ln\frac{y}{5}}{0.7}$$

$$x=e^\frac{\ln\frac{y}{5}}{0.7}$$

$$x=\left(\frac{y}{5}\right)^\frac{1}{0.7}$$

$$x=\left(\frac{y}{5}\right)^\frac{10}{7}$$